Kbuntu 23.10 Desktop doesn't "sleep"
When I hit the sleep button or execute sudo systemctl suspend, the screen goes off and then turns back on at the lockscreen. I have tried googling this issue, but can't get a solution yet.
Below are some details about my system
$ hostnamectl 
 Static hostname: testmachina403
       Icon name: computer-desktop
         Chassis: desktop 
      Machine ID: 2dabxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
         Boot ID: e22exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Operating System: Ubuntu 23.10                    
          Kernel: Linux 6.5.0-35-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
  Hardware Model: B550 GAMING X V2
Firmware Version: F14
   Firmware Date: Tue 2022-01-04

$ uname -a 
Linux testmachina403 6.5.0-35-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Apr 26 11:23:57 UTC 2024 x86_64
 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

This is the syslog
$ cat -n /var/log/syslog | grep -A 10 -B 3 suspend
 10965  2024-05-27T14:05:39.809052-05:00 testmachina403 systemd[1]: Reached target bluetooth.target - Bluetooth Support.
 10966  2024-05-27T14:05:39.820408-05:00 testmachina403 systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
 10967  2024-05-27T14:05:39.820592-05:00 testmachina403 systemd[1]: Finished systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend.
 10968  2024-05-27T14:05:39.820976-05:00 testmachina403 systemd[1]: Stopped target sleep.target - Sleep.
 10969  2024-05-27T14:05:39.821043-05:00 testmachina403 systemd[1]: Reached target suspend.target - Suspend.
 10970  2024-05-27T14:05:39.822911-05:00 testmachina403 NetworkManager[905]: <info>  [1716836739.8227] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
 10971  2024-05-27T14:05:39.822993-05:00 testmachina403 NetworkManager[905]: <info>  [1716836739.8228] device (enp8s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
 10972  2024-05-27T14:05:39.823191-05:00 testmachina403 ModemManager[916]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
 10973  2024-05-27T14:05:39.823247-05:00 testmachina403 systemd[1]: Starting grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB...
 10974  2024-05-27T14:05:39.823359-05:00 testmachina403 systemd[1]: Stopped target suspend.target - Suspend.

I can provide more debugging information if required.

Does this answer your question? Spurious wake after suspend

If the linked answer doesn't solve your problem, please reply back (and please begin the reply with @mchid so that I will get a notification) and I can retract the close vote.

Also, you may have to reboot or reload systemd and network manager at the very least after setting the configuration file.

@mchid, I tried doing that, but the system still auto wakes up. I tried looking at the syslog again and I still see NetworkManager[848]: <info>  [1717126167.9889] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)

After tons of troubleshooting, I found a solution. I toggled every entity in  /proc/acpi/wakeup file and identified the component that was causing the auto-wakeup. I wrote a systemd service to disable it at every boot.
The device was GPP0 which has the below device connected to it. I am not able to identify what is connected to this bridge though.
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])

After tons of troubleshooting, I found a solution. I toggled every entity in  /proc/acpi/wakeup file and identified the component that was causing the auto-wakeup. I wrote a systemd service to disable it at every boot.
The device was GPP0 which has the below device connected to it. I am not able to identify what is connected to this bridge though.
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])

Any help in identifying the underlying device is welcome.
